# My X-01 power armor keeps appearing in different parts of my settlement but i dont have any settlers

Tags: fallout-4, xbox-one

My X-01 Power Armor in Fallout 4 keeps moving to different places at the Redrocket Truck Stop where you find dog meat but I don't have any followers or settlers

Comment: Are you leaving the fusion core in it? Always take the fusion core out -- otherwise, anyone can just grab it and run around in it. That doesn't explain why it moves if you don't have any settlers, but still worth noting.

Comment: There are some NPCs that you can send to a location but that don't become formal settlers until you talk to them. Sheffield (beggar in Diamond City) and the Vault-Tec Rep (found at the hotel in Goodneighbor) are a couple examples. You don't happen to have any of these hanging around, do you?

Comment: Is your Power Armor upgraded at all? Do you find that the upgrades are lost when the armor moves location?

Comment: It only has the hod rod paint job and I sometimes leave the core in the armor so maybe that's it

Answer (score 1):

Even without settlers it is possible for other NPCs to use your power armor. Hostile raiders, merchant caravans, or even inactive companions are all capable of using power armor.

To protect against this take the fusion core out of the power armor to make it inoperable. NPCs are incapable of entering power armor without a fusion core and it's unlikely they'll find any lying around.

Alternatively, place your power armor somewhere they cannot reach it. NPCs cannot jump and they do not drop off of terrain (if possible). Place your armor somewhere they'd need to jump to reach or into a room they'd need to drop into and they'll avoid it.